# Assign a variable as a function parameter with the same name

Tags: javascript, function

I cant get why this isn't correct:

```
let a=5
a = a
//so there are no errors here. In the last statement javascript replaces the left side with a value, and that's it
```

Now if I write this:

```
let a=5
function hey(a=a){
return console.log(a)
}
hey()
```

This will return undefined, so the argument a=a does not get evaluated to `a=6`

---

The use case for having the same variable name is that I'd like to create a section in the beginning of the script with variables, and use the same names than I use in the functions later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example, you have **one** variable named `a`. You can assign the value to `a` to `a`. This is pointless, but possible.

In your second example, you have **two different variables** both named `a` which exist in different scopes. Inside the function declaration, `a` refers to the local variable `a` and not the global variable `a`. When you try to use `a` as the default value, it reads the locally scoped `a` which is `undefined`.

Use different names if you want to do that. It probably makes sense to organise them in an object too.

```js
const default_values = {
  a: 5
};

function hey(a = default_values.a) {
  console.log(a);
}

hey();
```

Comment: It's not pointless if you're trying to understand how it works. And also if I define let a; inside the function it will return an error of a being already declared. idk how you find this logic

Comment: @misternobody — If you declare `a` as a function parameter and then try to declare it again with `let` it will be a second declaration in the same scope.

Comment: what does it mean to declare a as a function parameter? is this re-declare 'a' but it won't throw an error?

Comment: `function (a, b, c) { }` declares three variables as function paramaters.

Comment: that's not the question. If we declara a=5; and then function hey(a,b,c){ } there is no error of re declaring a

Comment: They are variables in different scopes. So it isn't a redeclaration.

Comment: I see. I didn't know you could do that. Thanks

Comment: sorry to keep commenting here but maybe an object and then using destructuring makes sense? i'm just learning that

Comment: I don't see any benefit to involving destructuring in this example.

Comment: yeah my neither now